# Ampersand showing up encoded

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I checked my "profile feed"* just now, and saw this:

[image: Ampersand showing up as &]

As you can see, the ampersand in "Strunk & White" is showing up encoded.

I can't recall if this is a one time thing, or if I've seen it before.

Android 6.0.1

Android App Version 1.0.89

---

*Just to clarify, by "profile feed", I mean the feed that comes up when you open the sidebar, and click your username at the top; the one that gives an overview of all your activity. The main feed that pops up when you open the app shows the ampersand fine.